# Problem with user authentication in PHP and variables and program flow

Tags: php, authentication, variables

I have been working for 2 days on a login and authentication system in PHP. For my logic it should be perfect, but I have problems as usual.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

include "../navbar.php";
require_once '../database-connection.php';
include "../login.html";

if (isset($_SESSION['session_id'])) {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'] ?? '';
    $password = $_POST['password'] ?? '';

    $query = "
            SELECT email, password
            FROM users
            WHERE email = :email
        ";

    $check = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $check->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $check->execute();
    $user = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($email == $user['email']) {
        if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['session_id'] = session_id();
            $sql = "
                SELECT username, id FROM users
                WHERE email = :email";

            $check = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $check->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $check->execute();
            $user = $check->fetch();

            $_SESSION['session_user'] = $user['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];

            header('Location: ../index.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            $msg = "Wrong Password";
        }
    } else {
        $msg = "Wrong Email";
    }
    printf($msg, '<a href="../login.html">back</a>');
}
```

The system works, it allows me to authenticate the users registered in the database, but I don't understand why the `$msg` variable that I use for errors is not printed.
Or better any echo that I put in any part of the listing is not printed.
I can't print anything anywhere. It looks like the program just hangs after the first few includes, yet it lets me authenticate.

(Yes guys I debug by printing the echo to understand up where the scripts work!)

Comment: Be wary of specifically letting users know which part of the login process failed ( ie: `Wrong Password` and `Wrong Email` ) - a more generic message would be better.

Comment: FYI `if ($email == $user['email']) {` is unnecessary - your SQL query already took care of checking that. What you actually need to do there is check if the query returned any rows.

Comment: You don't need else after `exit`.

Comment: Why two select queries? As they both select from the same table a single query should suffice!?

Comment: 1) Why use `ob_start();`? It doesn't appear to be necessary? KISS.  2) Your `printf()` [sytnax is wrong](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php).

Comment: As an aside...`$_SESSION['session_id'] = session_id();`...why are you storing the session ID within the session? Can't quite work out why you'd need that.

Comment: thanks guys, in a few minutes you make me learn things that I can't learn from books alone.